# php nested heredoc and escaping variables

Tags: php, heredoc

I am using heredoc to create a php file which needs to use heredoc in the generated file as the file will create other files.

The `<<<EOD` bit works fine and I can see all the variables properly escaped.

The problem I'm having is the nested heredoc `<<<EOL` where `\$languageStrings` isn't escaped

If I use `\$languageStrings` and run the generated file ddd.php, the output is this:

```
<?php
 = Array (
    'LBL_LOCATION_INFORMATION' => 'Basic Information',
    'LBL_CUSTOM_INFORMATION' => 'Custom Information',
    'SINGLE_' => ''
);
```

if i use `\\$languageStrings` trying to esacpe the backslash i get:

```
<?php
\ = Array (
    'LBL_LOCATION_INFORMATION' => 'Basic Information',
    'LBL_CUSTOM_INFORMATION' => 'Custom Information',
    'SINGLE_' => ''
);
```

How can I correct this so i get `$languageStrings = Array (`? I did think about trying to open the file and insert into a specific line but the file will always be different.

I'm open to suggestions

Here is an example of my heredoc

```
$text = <<<EOD
This is some text
This is some more text

This is a \$variable //outputs this is a $variable

This is some more text
EOD;

$text .= <<<EOD
\n
\$targetpath = 'modules/' . \$moduleInstance->name;

if (!is_file(\$targetpath)) {
    mkdir(\$targetpath);
    mkdir(\$targetpath . '/language');
    // create the language file
    \$languagepath = 'languages/en_us';

    \$languageContents = <<<EOL
<?php
\$languageStrings = Array (
    'LBL_LOCATION_INFORMATION' => 'Basic Information',
    'LBL_CUSTOM_INFORMATION' => 'Custom Information',
    'SINGLE_\$moduleInstance->name' => '\$moduleInstance->name'
);
EOL;

    file_put_contents(\$languagepath . '/' . \$module->name . '.php', \$languageContents);
}
EOD;

file_put_contents('ddd.php', $text);
```

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it by creating a variable outside of the heredoc

```
$strings = '\$languageStrings';
```

and replacing `\$languageStrings` with `$strings = Array (` in the heredoc string

The output is what I expected

Answer (score 2):

Need a single quotes like **Heredoc**. This name is **Nowdoc**.
Nowdocs are to single-quoted strings what heredocs are to double-quoted strings.

```
$foo = "bar";
echo <<<STR
str $foo
STR;

echo <<<'STR'
str $foo
STR;
```

OR

```
echo "str $foo";
echo 'str $foo';
```

Expected Result:
->str bar
->str $foo

Since PHP 5.3.0, the opening Heredoc identifier may optionally be double quotes

```
<<<"FOO"
FOO;
```

same as

```
<<<FOO
FOO;
```

I prefer use every time double-quoted heredoc for intelligibility, although it is optional.

Doc says: [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc)

> Nowdocs are to single-quoted strings what heredocs are to
>   double-quoted strings. A nowdoc is specified similarly to a heredoc,
>   but no parsing is done inside a nowdoc. The construct is ideal for
>   embedding PHP code or other large blocks of text without the need for
>   escaping. It shares some features in common with the SGML  construct, in that it declares a block of text which is not for
>   parsing.
>
> A nowdoc is identified with the same <<< sequence used for heredocs,
>   but the identifier which follows is enclosed in single quotes, e.g.
>   <<<'EOT'. All the rules for heredoc identifiers also apply to nowdoc
>   identifiers, especially those regarding the appearance of the closing
>   identifier.